# Wordpress Select Files button not working on iPhone

Tags: iphone, wordpress, safari

Not only does the Safari browser button on iOS work, but it works in chrome.
What can be the problems for 2 days I can not understand this
IOS version 13.4.1
Wordpress version 5.4

Comment: Can you provide more detail?  Some code, some screenshots, anything?  It could be something as simple as another element overlapping it in Safari but not chrome.  But no one can answer without more information.

Comment: https://youtu.be/_wjFvHAcCdc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to leave this for the time being.  This is now a known bug in WordPress Core, there appears to be a fix available and will be part of 5.4.1.

You can follow along with the debugging, investigation and updates here:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/49753#comment:22

The problem was identified about three weeks and the test release is due today, so an update can be expected in the next few weeks. *(Based on what I read, don't hold me to those timelines.)*

In earnest, I'd shelf this as an issue and move on to other development work you've got to do - no point in working on this when the fix is already complete and will be pushed shortly.

I know this isn't a solution but at least now you know the cause and that it's being handled.

Comment: If that answered your question please accept so other users know this is a legitimate concern.